Revenuecat purchase problem in Flutter iOS
static Future<bool> fetchAndPurchaseLifetimeAccess() async {
    try {
      // Fetch offerings
      Offerings offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
      Offering? offering = offerings.current;
      //Printing offerings
      offerings.all.forEach(
        (key, value) {
          print("Offerings are ; $key : $value");
        },
      );
      // Check if lifetime package is available
      if (offering != null && offering.lifetime != null) {
        debugPrint('Found Lifetime Offering');
        // Purchase the lifetime package
        CustomerInfo purchaserInfo =
            await Purchases.purchasePackage(offering.lifetime!);
        // Check if the entitlement is active
        if (purchaserInfo.entitlements.all["zsp2_id"]?.isActive == true) {
          debugPrint("Lifetime access granted!");

          SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          // Save premium info on SharedPref
          await prefs.setBool('isPremium', true);
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        debugPrint("Lifetime package not available.");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Error purchasing: $e");
    }
    return false;
  }

Output:
flutter: Trying to purchase
flutter: Error purchasing: PlatformException(23, There is an issue with your configuration. Check the underlying error for more details. There's a problem with your configuration. None of the products registered in the RevenueCat dashboard could be fetched from App Store Connect (or the StoreKit Configuration file if one is being used).
flutter: More information: https://rev.cat/why-are-offerings-empty, {readable_error_code: CONFIGURATION_ERROR, underlyingErrorMessage: , message: There is an issue with your configuration. Check the underlying error for more details. There's a problem with your configuration. None of the products registered in the RevenueCat dashboard could be fetched from App Store Connect (or the StoreKit Configuration file if one is being used).
flutter: More information: https://rev.cat/why-are-offerings-empty, code: 23, readableErrorCode: CONFIGURATION_ERROR}, null)

What's wrong here?
Revenuecat iOS setup in documentation is little bit confusing.

Did you see this?
